# Google Visualization API - Multi-Line Chart

Tags: php, google-visualization, linechart

I've an array created after pulling records from the database. The array is like:

```
// $xyz array
Array
(
    [f30] => Array
        (
            [December 2012] => 71
            [November 2012] => 70
            [October 2012] => 66
        )    

    [f32] => Array
        (
            [December 2012] => 85
            [November 2012] => 83
            [October 2012] => 81
        )
)
```

If it were a single line chart, I'm able to plot it effortlessly. However, when I try to plot a multi-line chart, I'm running into a lot of problems. Below is the code that I'm attempting to plot the data with:

#### PHP

```
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
           array('label' => 'Month', 'type' => 'string')        
         );

$rows = array();
foreach($xyz as $form=>$hhh)
{        
   $table['cols'][] = array('label'=>$form, 'type'=>'number');
   foreach($hhh as $mnth=>$pt)
   {
      $temp = array();
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $mnth);
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $pt);
      $rows[] = array('c'=>$temp);
    }
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

#### JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});    
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'Some title',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };            
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('divID'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

I've tried various permutations and combinations by changing the positions of `$temp`, `$rows` and `$table['rows']` arrays, but I can't seem to plot two lines in a single graph. I'm probably messing up the placement of the arrays.

The closest I managed to get was like the one below:

[image: What I got]

But my expected output is something like
[image: What I'm looking for]

`f30` and `f31` go in place of `Sales` and `Expenses` and `October`, `November`, and `December` go in place of `2004`, `2005`, `2006`, `2007`

Comment: You want a table with 3 columns: Column A has the dates (in date format, so `new Date(2012,9,1)` for instance, so they order properly). You can use strings as you are, but need to care about order. Column B has the values for F30. Column C has the values for F31. Manipulate your data to end up that way, and it will work. I am not sure of how you are getting the array to a datatable, so I can't be more specific unless you share how you are actually passing it in to the google charts API.

Comment: That's the issue @jmac I can't seem to know how to make 3 columns from the array.

Comment: How are you creating the array? What is the data you're getting from the database? There's really no way for you to put the data in a different format? You can create an array within an array, and then loop through the sub-array for each data point (so you'd have Nov 2012, then [70, 83] for instance). But there's no way to give a specific solution with the information currently presented (it's too broad, there isn't a clear sense of which things you can/can't change)

Comment: Ok. lets forget about the database. Let's just say I've hardcoded values just as `$xyz` array contains. What form do I need to convert `$xyz` to draw a multi line chart? I've gone through the `Google Code Playground` but it doesn't contain an example using PHP arrays.

Comment: @jmac No worries. I figured it out. Thanks for your time though

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Looks like an array in an array worked for you. Sorry I couldn't give more specific help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. My god! What a relief it is. I just had to have an array in this format:

```
Array
(
    [December 2012] => Array
        (
            [0] => 71
            [1] => 85
        )

    [November 2012] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70
            [1] => 83                
        )

    [October 2012] => Array
        (
            [0] => 66
            [1] => 81
        )

)
```

The rest was a small modification in the `foreach` loop and voila! It was done.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a data table for each f[30] and f[31]
and then do 
[google.visualization.data.join()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join)

This basically joins the two charts off the key column - i.e.